# How to get Chrome to remember my Google password?

Tags: authentication

When logging into Gmail Chrome will not offer to save the password. It's not in the block list - Chrome simply never offers to save it.

Plus, at the moment (10:30 5th December 2018) - the 2FA doesn't appear to be sending texts to my phone. I just login as though it's not enabled. I have checked though - it's still on. :-(

Answer (score 1):

On the top right side of your Chrome browser, there are the 3 dots, click on it.

You will see ‘**settings**’; click on it.

Scroll all the way down and you will see “**Passwords**”; click on it.

Turn on this two button[image]

Comment: After clicking "advanced" there is no option called "Passwords and Forms"

Comment: Got it - had to sign out of Chrome and Google and then sign back into Google.

Comment: NB "Signing out of Chrome" means signing out of Chrome sync

Comment: of course yes if you log out your main google account you will out of chrome sync